# Getting a collection property of a class take a property of another class of another type?

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to first thank you all for the help you've given me implicitly over the last few months!  I've gone from not knowing how to access the VBA IDE in Excel to writing fully integrated analysis programs for work.  I couldn't have done it without the community here.

I'm currently trying to overhaul the first iteration of a data analysis program I wrote while learning how to code in VBA.  While purpose driven and only really legible to myself, the code worked; but was a mess.  From folks on this site I picked up Martin's Clean Code and gave it a read on how to try and be a better programmer.

From Martin's Clean Code, it was impressed on me to prioritize abstraction and decoupling of my code to allow for higher degrees of maintenance and modularization.  I found this out the hard way since very minor changes requested above my pay grade would require *massive* and confusing rewrites!  I'm trying to eliminate that problem going forward.

I am attempting to rewrite my code in terms of single responsibility classes (at least, where it is possible) and I am a bit confused.  I apologize if my question isn't clear or if I'm using the wrong terminology.  I want to be able to generate a collection of specific strings (the names of our detectors to be specific) with no duplicates from raw instrument data files from my lab.  The purpose of this function is to assemble a bunch of metadata in a class and use it to standardize our file system and prevent clerical errors from newbies and old hands when they use the analysis program.

The testing initialization sub is below.  It pops open a userform asking for the user to select the filepaths of the three files in the rawdatafiles class; then it kills the userform to free memory.  The metadata object is currently for testing and will be rewritten properly when I get the output I want:

```
Sub setup()
GrabFiles.Show
Set rawdatafiles = New cRawDataFiles
rawdatafiles.labjobFile = GrabFiles.tboxLabJobFile.value
rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount = GrabFiles.tboxOriginal.value
rawdatafiles.rawdatasecondcount = GrabFiles.tboxRecount.value
Set GrabFiles = Nothing

Dim temp As cMetaData
Set temp = New cMetaData
temp.labjobName = rawdatafiles.labjobFile 
'this works fine!
temp.detectorsOriginal = rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount 
' This throws run time error 424: Object Required

End Sub
```

The cMetadata class I have currently is as follows:

```
Private pLabjobName As String
Private pDetectorsOriginal As Collection
Private pDetectorsRecheck As Collection

Private Sub class_initialize()
    Set pDetectorsOriginal = New Collection
    Set pDetectorsRecheck = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get labjobName() As String
    labjobName = pLabjobName
End Property

Public Property Let labjobName(fileName As String)
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    pLabjobName = FSO.GetBaseName(fileName)
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Property

Public Property Get detectorsOriginal() As Collection
    detectorsOriginal = pDetectorsOriginal
End Property

Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)
    pDetectorsOriginal = getDetectors(rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount)
End Property
```

When I step through the code it starts reading the "public property get rawdatafirstcount() as string" and throws the error after "End Property" and points back to the "temp.detectorsOriginal = rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount" line in the initialization sub.

I think I'm at least close because the `temp.labjobName = rawdatafiles.labjobFile` code executes properly.  I've tried playing around with the data types since this is a collection being assigned by a string but I unsurprisingly get data type errors and can't seem to figure out how to proceed.

If everything worked the way I want it to, the following function would take the filepath string from the `rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount` property and return for me a collection containing detector names as strings with no duplicates (I don't know if this function works exactly the way I want since I haven't been able to get the filepath I want to parse properly in the initial sub; but I can deal that later!):

```
Function getDetectors(filePath As String) As Collection
Dim i As Integer
Dim detectorsCollection As Collection
Dim OriginalRawData As Workbook

Set OriginalRawData = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
Set detectorsCollection = New Collection

For i = 1 To OriginalRawData.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    detectorsCollection.Add OriginalRawData.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).value, CStr(OriginalRawData.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).value)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
getDetectors = detectorsCollection

Set detectorsCollection = Nothing
Set OriginalRawData = Nothing

End Function
```

Thanks again for reading and any help you can offer!

Comment: Make sure you have your error handling at "break in class module" or you won't get to debug your classes...

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you are missing a `Set` keyword: `temp.detectorsOriginal = rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount` .

Comment: Also, once you figure out the problem and want help with cleaning up the code more, consider throwing this up on CodeReview. There'sa  bunch of opportunity here, but a critique of the code is outside of the scope of SO. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba

Comment: The parameter of a `Property Set` (or `Property Let`) member is given by the right-hand side (RHS) of the assignment expression. In other words this `originalFilepath` parameter that you're not using, is what the calling code means to assign the property to - e.g. given `Set foo.detectorsOriginal = bar`, then `bar` is the reference you receive with `originalFilepath` - and you're not doing anything with it, which makes the property extremely confusing to use. Definitely head over to [codereview.se] once you get your code to work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> temp.detectorsOriginal = rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount 
> ' This throws run time error 424: Object Required
> ```

It throws an error because, as others have already stated, the `Set` keyword is missing.

Now with that out of the way, a `Set` keyword is **NOT** what you want here. In fact, sticking a `Set` keyword in front of that assignment will only buy you another error.

Let's look at this property you're invoking:

> ```
> Public Property Get detectorsOriginal() As Collection
>     detectorsOriginal = pDetectorsOriginal
> End Property
>
> Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)
>     pDetectorsOriginal = getDetectors(rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount)
> End Property
> ```

You're trying to assign `detectorsOriginal` with what appears to be some `String` value that lives in some `TextBox` control on that form you're showing - but the property's type is `Collection`, which is an object type - and that's not a `String`!

Now look at the property that *does* work:

> ```
> Public Property Get labjobName() As String
>     labjobName = pLabjobName
> End Property
>
> Public Property Let labjobName(fileName As String)
>     Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
>     pLabjobName = FSO.GetBaseName(fileName)
>     Set FSO = Nothing
> End Property
> ```

This one is a `String` property, with a `Property Let` mutator that uses the `fileName` parameter it's given.

The broken one:

> ```
> Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)
>     pDetectorsOriginal = getDetectors(rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount)
> End Property
> ```

Is a `Set` mutator, takes a `Collection` parameter, and doesn't use the `originalFilepath` parameter it's given at all!

And this is where I'm confused about your intention: you're passing what has all the looks of a `String` except for its type (`Collection`) - the calling code wants to give it a `String`.

In other words the calling code is expecting this:

```
Public Property Let detectorsOriginal(ByVal originalFilepath As String)
```

See, I don't know what you meant to be doing here; it appears you're missing some `pOriginalFilepath As String` private field, and then `detectorsOriginal` would be some get-only property that returns some collection:

```
Private pOriginalFilePath As String

Public Property Get OriginalFilePath() As String
    OriginalFilePath = pOriginalFilePath
End Property

Public Property Let OriginalFilePath(ByVal value As String)
    pOriginalFilePath = value
End Property
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I can tell you this:

- Don't make a `Property Set` member that ignores its parameter, it's terribly confusing code.
- Don't make a `Property` (`Get/Let/Set`) member that does anything non-trivial. If it's not trivially simple and has a greater-than-zero chance of throwing an error, it probably shouldn't be a property. Make it a method (`Sub`, or `Function` if it needs to return a value) instead.

A word about this:

> ```
> Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
> pLabjobName = FSO.GetBaseName(fileName)
> Set FSO = Nothing
> ```

Whenever you `Dim` something `As New`, VBA will automatically instantiate the object whenever it's referred to. In other words, this wouldn't throw any errors:

```
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Set FSO = Nothing
pLabjobName = FSO.GetBaseName(fileName)
```

Avoid `As New` if you can. In this case you don't even need a local variable - use a `With` block instead:

```
With New FileSystemObject
    pLabjobName = .GetBaseName(fileName)
End With
```

Comment: This post (actually all of the posts) has been amazingly helpful.  I am having a mental hurdle over get/let/set statements and getting corresponding data types to parse through them.  In one sentence, what I'm trying to do is:  Take a class 'blueprint' that is going to contain a collection and generate that collection through its property taking a filepath string from another class.  The meta-goal is keeping the single responsibility principle present for my classes.  I am still fiddling with what you've suggested and will report back when I've made some headway!  Thank you!

Comment: @mooreppj great! Feel free to mark any of them as "accepted", by clicking the hollow checkmark next to one of them (near the up/down voting buttons)

Answer (score 1):

May not be your issue but you're missing `Set` in your `detectorsOriginal` Set/Get methods:

```
Public Property Get detectorsOriginal() As Collection
    Set detectorsOriginal = pDetectorsOriginal
End Property

Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)
    Set pDetectorsOriginal = getDetectors(rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount)
End Property
```

Comment: I would like to raise a critical-level red flag about the unused `originalFilepath` parameter. Something about that `Property Set` strikes me as a terrible mistake. When I do `Set foo.Bar = Nothing`, I expect `foo.Bar` to be `Set` to `Nothing`. This property won't do that.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - worth pointing out.  I was only looking at the missing `Set`

Comment: Yes, and then with that `Set` restored, a new error pops up on the same line - worth addressing IMO (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

So the error is one I've made a time or two (or more).  Whenever you assign an object to another object, you have to use the Set reserved word to assign the reference to the Object.

In your code do the following:

In `Sub setup()`

```
Set temp.detectorsOriginal = rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount
```

And in the cMetadata class change the `Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)` property to the following:

```
Public Property Get detectorsOriginal() As Collection
   Set detectorsOriginal = pDetectorsOriginal
End Property

Public Property Set detectorsOriginal(originalFilepath As Collection)
    Set pDetectorsOriginal = getDetectors(rawdatafiles.rawdatafirstcount)
End Property
```

Also in your function `Function getDetectors(filePath as String) as Collection change the statement after`Next i` to

```
Set getDetectors = detectorsCollection
```

Also, I'm very glad to hear that you've learned how to use VBA.

When you're ready to create your own Custom Collections, check out this post. [Your own custom Collections](http://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/your-own-classes-in-vba.htm).

I also book marked Paul Kelly's Excel Macro Mastery [VBA Class Modules – The Ultimate Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules) as well as his [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#What_is_the_VBA_Dictionary).

If you haven't been to [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) you should do so.  He has a ton of useful code that will help your delivery your projects more quickly.

Happy Coding.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `originalFilepath` parameter in the `detectorsOriginal` property `Set` mutator? That parameter is the RHS of the assignment expression (i.e. it's `rhs` in `Set foo.detectorsOriginal = rhs`), which means this `Property Set` isn't doing what's expected of a `Property Set` member, which makes for rather confusing code. EDIT: just noticed it was in the OP... definitely not the only problem in this code...

Comment: The `Set` mutator is the signature of the property. The code within the property must use required VBA syntax.  Remember, a mutator (i.e., Get, Set, Let) is really just a function call.  Object Oriented compilers provide this mutator notation for readability.

Comment: I know what a mutator is, thank you - I have a whole blog about advanced OOP in VBA, and manage an open-source project that extends the VBIDE. BTW `Property Get` is an *accessor*. The point is that OP's `Property Set` RHS parameter isn't used, which means that property doesn't behave the way one would expect at all.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure how to answer your question.  This is how it works in VBA.

Comment: I didn't ask a question... I commented about an unused parameter, but really that comment was meant for the OP (realized after posting). And no, the way the OP has their property written isn't "how it works in VBA" - or in any other language for that matter. When you do `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn` you have all rights to expect that `Property Set ActiveConnection` to take your `conn` object and assign it to whatever it is that `ActiveConnection` is encapsulating - this isn't any different. An unused RHS parameter in a property mutator is nothing less than a bug, if not a bad design issue.

Comment: You're right, but it's not my code.  I'm only pointing out that you have to use set in the property to assign an object reference.  Might it cause an error, maybe, but that wasn't the question